# Como aplicar en css3 bordes redondeado con degradado

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3

Hola estoy queriendo aplicar a una caja bordes redondeados con degradados pero no logro hacerlo, si bien el degradado lo aplica los bordes no, quisiera que quedarancomo el ejemplo que adjunto[image: imagen adjunta]

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid green;  
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(#a42e6e, #783057);
  border-image-slice: 20;
  padding: 2em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="box">
    <h4 class="titulo-degradado-1">
      174
    </h4>
    <p>Atención al vecino</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola, lo unico que necesitas son bordes redondeados degradados? te paso ejemplo si me dices que si

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo que hice son los bordes redondeados con degradado y el texto degradado https://codepen.io/ankynator/pen/zYoROQO

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma lo puedes Manejar con tus colores. no tengo méritos en esta respuesta, te dejo el [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963/possible-to-use-border-radius-together-with-a-border-image-which-has-a-gradient) de donde vi la información.

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: white;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    padding: 10px;
}


.box::after{

    position: absolute;
    top: -4px; bottom: -4px;
    left: -4px; right: -4px;
    background: linear-gradient(#a42e6e, #783057);
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 16px;

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <h4 class="titulo-degradado-1">
      174
    </h4>
    <p>Atención al vecino</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Santiago

Comment: @blonfu tienes razon ya mismo lo corrijo

Comment: @MarianoFranco edite la respuesta para que puedas conservar el degradado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ver ejemplos [Aqui](https://codepen.io/Afonin/pen/eJGqNX).

Espero que te pueda ayudar, Saludos.

Comment: Las respuestas no deben ser sólo un enlace porque con el tiempo podría dejar de estar accesible y ya no valdría. Además esos ejemplos no tienen bordes redondeados.

Comment: Muchas graciass